# Move down the scroll when you click a photo (html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I click on the image, it is supposed to move me to another part of the scroll. Problem is, the image is included in a header (like a banner) which initiated as a class. How could i implement js code inside an image that belongs to that class? Or should i create a class inside a class?

Comment: Quick'n'dirty way would be hooking another click event to that image and use whatever code you want. You can use document.querySelector to locate the image element and then element.addEventListener for the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to use javascript at all

You can place your `img` inside `a` tag with `href="#id-of-element"`. In in some other place in your html you can place element with `id="id-of-element"`. In that case when you click on img it will scroll you to this element (it will not be a smooth scroll but more like 'teleportation').

If you insist on smooth scroll then you can do it like that. This will cover all anchors like `a href="#..."` but if you want it to only work on this very image you can replace `a[href^="#"]` with classname/id of your image.

*This example for some reason doesn't work here for some reason but work locally, so you have to check this yourself* 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

```css
document.querySelector('a[href^="#"]').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const id = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    document.querySelector(id).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "nearest"});
});
```

```html
<a href="#id-of-element">
  this is image
</a>

<div style="height: 1000px"></div>

<div id="id-of-element">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `document.querySelector(selector)`

selector example - `.header .banner img`